# problems about the mail command in linux

Tags: linux, email, shell, debian

I want to send email with mail command, but it didn't work.

I use the following command :

```
mail -v -s "test" jidalyg_8711@163.com
```

then the terminal will always wait and no response.
Also, there is nothing in the /var/log/mail
 Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

By the way, my operating system is debian

Comment: Also, I can ping smtp.163.com .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After that command, the process running `mail` is waiting for input on *stdin*, that you should end with Ctrl-D (end of file).

You can also pipe or redirect or use a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

Exemple of using a pipe:

```
 date | mail -s "now is" jidalyg_8711@163.com
```

Typing a message

```
 mail -s "a message" jidalyg_8711@163.com
 body of your message
 end it with Ctrl-D
```

Redirecting a file containing the body

```
 mail -s "a message in file" jidalyg_8711@163.com < mailbody.txt
```

Using a here document

```
 mail -s "a here doc" jidalyg_8711@163.com <<ENDMSG
    this is the here doc
    ended by the line below
 ENDMSG
```

Answer (score 5):

`mail` is an interactive program if you don't feed something into the standard input. Therefore you have to interactively enter some message body and finish the text by a line containing only a `.`.

E.g.:

```
mail -v -s "test" jidalyg_8711@163.com
Some text
.
```

Or you could pipe some text into `mail`'s standard input:

```
echo "some text" | mail -v -s "test" jidalyg_8711@163.com
```